# Detect x date then make visible MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to detect x date and if it's x date then mcBulb to be visible.

```
var my_date:Date = new Date();
trace(my_date);

function checkdate():void {

    if (my_date =="Sat Aug 16 2014 16:13:23" ) {
mcBulb.visible=true;

} else {
mcBulb.visible=false;
}

}
```

Comment: I gave you the answer, you have just to adapt your code. Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`AS3 Date class`](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html).

Its arguments are: year, month (-1), date, hour, minute, second, millisecond. Note that the months starting from 0 in AS3, you'll have to write month - 1.

Then if your date is : *Sat Aug 16 2014 16:13:23*, your `new Date` will be:

```
var myNewDate:Date = new Date(2014, 7, 16, 16, 13, 23, 0);
```

The code below shows how you can use this class to count down:

```
var now:Date;
var target:Date = new Date(2014, 7, 16, 16, 13, 23, 0); 
var targetTime = target.getTime();
var actualTime:Number;
var timeLeft:Number;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countDown);

function countDown(e:Event):void {
    now = new Date();
    actualTime = now.getTime();
    timeLeft = targetTime - actualTime;
    if (timeLeft < 0) trace('time is elapsed');
}
```